# Bug in Question's number of Views after favoriting it

Tags: bug

This is my first post on meta.

I noticed that after I favorite any of my own Questions the Number of views is increased by one?

Is that a bug?

Comment: It only happens when you favourite your own question, not anyone elses...

Comment: @ben any source or reason for that?

Comment: I tested it @JohannesKuhn.